# Longest path in a Graph with Dijkstra

Tags: graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, dijkstra, longest-path

I was just wondering: can you inverse all the weights in a graph and then do a Dijkstra? As we are minimizing the reciprocal values of the weights, the obtained path would maximize it all in all, right?
So, in that way, we can obtain the longest path in a graph using Dijkstra!
It seems too easy, am I mistaken? Please, enlighten me.

Comment: What do you mean by inverse?

Comment: @NiVeR If i have x < y do 1/x > 1/y

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do so because the `longest path problem` doesn't have the optimal substructure problem as the `shortest path` one.

Say that you can consider any path as longest path (so it can have cycles) but if there is a cycle and the weights are positive the algorithm will never end since it can always improve the longest path by looping through the cycle.

Now say that we want to have only simple paths (without cycle) as candidates for the longest path. Consider, without loss of generality, the following graph with unitary weights for all edges:

```
A------B
|      |
|      |
C------D
```

And consider the longest path from `A` to `D` (`A->B->D`). For the problem to have optimal substructure property it must be the case that longest path from `A` to `B`is `A -> B` but clearly it isn't because path `A->C->D->B` is longer. Similar argument can be done for the path from `B` to `D`. So we can see why this problem can't be solved with Dijkstra algorithm. As a matter of fact this problem is `NP`, there isn't a reasonable time complexity solution.

Comment: but I said about inverting the weights and then find the shortest path, which in reality will be the longest because we are using the reciprocal values !!

Comment: Read again slowly.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I was thinking about an arbitrage problem. There, to find the sequence with the highest exchange rate I thought about inverting the values that are not all unitary.

Comment: @alienflow It was just a simple example. You can put other values like `(A,B)=1/2, (B,D)=1/4, (A,C) = 1/3, (C,B)=1.4`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to understand with a simple example graph.

[image]

Suppose you want to go from point A to point D. To minimize the reciprocal values of the weights, you will go through C. But A->B->D is larger.

**Edit**: Perhaps I should include some math at least.

Suppose the sum of a sequence of positive numbers is s.

`a1 + a2 + a3 + ... + an = s`.

What's the minimum value of reciprocal sum?

`1/a1 + 1/a2 + 1/a3 + ... + 1/an`

Playing around this will give you some intuition.